# Submit a form in jquery php after time out?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

jquery form submit function not working in php, i want to submit the form after time out, but its not working my code is as folows. Any one give me the solution for it

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var c=10;
        var t;
        timedCount();

        function timedCount()
        {
            var hours = parseInt( c / 3600 ) % 24;
            var minutes = parseInt( c / 60 ) % 60;
            var seconds = c % 60;
            var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
            $('#timer').html(result);
            if(c == 0 )
            {
                // form.submit();
                //$('#scoretarget').submit();
                //setConfirmUnload(false);
                document.formsubmit.submit();
                //alert("Your form  will be submited");
                //$( "#scoretarget" ).submit();
                // $('#scoretarget').submit();
                //$( "#target" ).submit();
                //window.location="logout.html";
            }else{
                c = c - 1;
                t = setTimeout(function(){
                        timedCount()
                    },1000);
            }
       }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: do you want to submit the form on page load?

Comment: Please check it is rendering in in your if condition put alert and check

Comment: this code will navigate to `congrasulations.php` so it all depends on what `congrasulations.php` it actually does, can you share it here ?

Comment: ya if() block is working fine but the form is not submitting when the if block is executed. alert(); is also working fine here only thing is form is not submitting i tried so many methods but it is not submitting

Comment: Are you getting any error in your browser console ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
                var c=10;
                var t;
                timedCount();

                function timedCount()
                {

                    var hours = parseInt( c / 3600 ) % 24;
                    var minutes = parseInt( c / 60 ) % 60;
                    var seconds = c % 60;
                    var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
                    $('#timer').html(result);
                    if(c == 0 )
                    {
                        // form.submit();
                        //$('#scoretarget').submit();
                        //setConfirmUnload(false);
                        //document.formsubmit.submit();
                        alert("Your form  will be submited");
                        $("#scoretarget" ).submit();
                        // $('#scoretarget').submit();
                        //$( "#target" ).submit();
                        //window.location="logout.html";
                    }
                    else{
                        c = c - 1;
                        
                        t = setTimeout(function(){
                            timedCount()
                        },
                        1000);
                    }
                }
            });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <form id="scoretarget" name="formsubmit" action="congrasulations.php" method="POST">
        </form>
    <div id="timer"></div>
```

Try including a jquery and submit the form with `$( "#scoretarget" ).submit();`.

Here is the entire HTML code instead of snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                var c=10;
                var t;
                timedCount();

                function timedCount()
                {

                    var hours = parseInt( c / 3600 ) % 24;
                    var minutes = parseInt( c / 60 ) % 60;
                    var seconds = c % 60;
                    var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
                    $('#timer').html(result);
                    if(c == 0 )
                    {
                        // form.submit();
                        //$('#scoretarget').submit();
                        //setConfirmUnload(false);
                        //document.formsubmit.submit();
                        alert("Your form  will be submited");
                        $("#scoretarget" ).submit();
                        // $('#scoretarget').submit();
                        //$( "#target" ).submit();
                        //window.location="logout.html";
                    }
                    else{
                        c = c - 1;

                        t = setTimeout(function(){
                            timedCount()
                        },
                        1000);
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
        <form id="scoretarget" name="formsubmit" action="congrasulations.php" method="POST">
        </form>
        <div id="timer"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: just try my HTML code in a separate file and let me know if it doesn't work.   i was redirected to congrasulations.php after submitting the form. in case you are note redirectedt check the error in your console.

Answer (score 0):

Submit form using code below instead of document.formsubmit.submit();

```
    $('#formId')[0].submit();
```

and check if there is any element in the form named as 'submit' in your form and if there is any, change the element's name to some other name because it may prevent your form from submission

Comment: $('#formId')[0].submit(); in this for what [0] refers to

Comment: Because when you call $( "#form_id" ).submit(); it triggers the external submit handler which prevents the default action

Comment: have you made any input element named 'submit' in your form?

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">

Comment: change the name of this element to something else because this may also prevent your form being submitted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125562/discussion-between-venu-gopal-and-sheetal).

Answer (score 0):

1.this code

```
else{
    c = c - 1;
    t = setTimeout(function(){
        timedCount()
    }, 
    1000);
}
```

should be:

```
else{
    t = setTimeout(function(){
        timedCount();
        c = c - 1;
    }, 
    1000);
}
```

Previously, your code only decrement the `c` once.
You should decrement `c` **inside** the `setTimeout` callback function so it would be decremented by the timeout value, which is 1000ms.

2.to trigger form submit in jQuery, use:
`$('form').trigger('submit');`

Source: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: <input type="submit" name="proceed" value="proceed" class="btn btn-default">

Comment: check my edit, you need to trigger the form submit using `$('form').trigger('submit');`